# Magento 2 REST API: Show In-stock products first in product listing API

Tags: magento2, product, rest-api, stock, product-sorting

I am looking into a headless magento approach. I am using the following API to list the products in a given category:

> V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=category_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=:category_id

I need to sort these results, so the In-stock products come first, then are followed by the out of stock ones.

I have also managed to add their stock status in extension_attributes as follows:

```
"extension_attributes": {
            "qty": "Out of Stock"
  }
```

Any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

Comment: hey, did you get any solution on this?